# Stacking Columns in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

I'm having some trouble with basics of Jetpack Compose. If I'm stacking columns like in Example One, it works fine. In Example Two, the height modifiers do not work, and any successive column will fill the entire screen, overwriting the first.

I guess the main question is, why does height not affect columns when they're not using a ConstraintLayout?

EXAMPLE ONE:

```
ConstraintLayout (modifier = Modifier
) {
    val startGuideline = createGuidelineFromTop(0.2f)
    val (statsLayout, boardLayout) = createRefs()

    Column (modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(100.dp)
        .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.light_grey))
        .constrainAs(statsLayout) {
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            bottom.linkTo(startGuideline)
        }
    )

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(150.dp)
        .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.teal_200))
        .constrainAs(boardLayout) {
            top.linkTo(startGuideline)
        }
    ) {
    }
}
```

EXAMPLE TWO:

```
Column (modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .height(100.dp)
    .background(colorResource(id = R.color.lighter_grey)),
) {
}

Column(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .height(100.dp)
    .background(colorResource(id = R.color.teal_200))
) {
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To stack the columns without Constraints layout, you have to add an outer `Column` that contains the two columns in your example two, it should be like this:

```
Column {

    Column (modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(100.dp)
        .background(
            color = Color.LightGray
        ),
    ) {
        Text(text = "Column 1 - Text 1")
        Text(text = "Column 1 - Text 2")
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(100.dp)
        .background(
            colorResource(
                id =
                R.color.teal_200
            )
        )
    ) {
        Text(text = "Column 2 - Text 1")
        Text(text = "Column 2 - Text 2")
    }

}
```

You can apply any modifier you need on the outer `Column` as well.

Code Result:

[image: Code Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use LazyColumn for creating stack of items like the below code, here negative Arrangement.spacedBy is giving the stack effect to items of lazy column

```
@Composable
fun CardsStackView(cards: List<CardUiModel> = getMockedCards()) {
    LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy((-50).dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 50.dp, end = 10.dp, start = 10.dp)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(cards) { index, card ->
            CardView(index, card)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CardView(index: Int, cardUiModel: CardUiModel) {
    Card(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(80.dp)
            .width(260.dp)
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = getCardColor(index)
        ) {
            Box(contentAlignment = Center) {
                Text(text = cardUiModel.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun getMockedCards() = listOf(
    CardUiModel("Visa"),
    CardUiModel("Amex"),
    CardUiModel("Rupay"),
    CardUiModel("Master Card")
)

private fun getCardColor(index: Int) =
    when (index) {
        0 -> Color.Blue
        1 -> Color.Magenta
        2 -> Color.Cyan
        3 -> Color.Red
        else -> Color.Yellow
    }

data class CardUiModel(val name: String)


@Preview(showBackground = true, device = Devices.PIXEL_XL)
@Composable
fun CardsStackViewPreview() {
    MaterialTheme {
        CardsStackView()
    }
}
```

It will look like the below Image

[image]